# React Native-- advanced example on FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have created a game using react and now I am trying to do the necessary changes to my code+styling so the game runs on mobile devices through ReactNative. The following code is from the official guides regarding [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html).

```
1. class MyList extends React.PureComponent { 
2. state = {selected: (new Map(): Map<string, boolean>)}; 
3. _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id; 
4. _onPressItem = (id: string) => {  
// updater functions are preferred for transactional updates
5. this.setState((state) => {  
// copy the map rather than modifying state.
6. const selected = new Map(state.selected); 
7. selected.set(id, !selected.get(id)); // toggle
8. return {selected}; }); };
```

While I have used both es6 arrow functions and Maps before, I honestly have a hard time understanding the syntax being used in the following two occasions:

a) Line 2: what's `(new Map(): Map<string, boolean>)` suppose to return?

b) Line 4: an arrow function that takes as an argument a... symbol? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line 2, just initializes the state with a Map type  (see Map here:
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map )

new Map() is how you create a Map, and the part after is the "Flow" type specification. It's Facebook's own static type checker library for Javascript (see here:[https://flow.org/en/docs/types/arrays/](https://flow.org/))

Maps are similar to objects in JS, but they have differences like, keys can be anything, they're iterable, they can be bigger, etc.

Line 4: As you can see in Flow you can specify the type on the arguments,
so you're basically expecting that "id" should be a string

Comment: Hey you are right, it is using flow.. I find it very strange that they did not feel the urge of saying so, I mean is not like flow is super popular. The syntax is very strange though and I felt rightly I think, confused. I ve worked with Maps before but this is something completely different..